# How to change the forward slash to the back slash using java?

Tags: java, string, replace

I have to store the value inside the `image` variable. Image is Object. It is store a string value format from database for `D:/Server/data/uploadedfile/12874c9be4308ddfdee9c10e5ffea507.png`. I need change to `D:\Server\data\uploadedfile\12874c9be4308ddfdee9c10e5ffea507.png`. But I was always trying all option of `strurl.replace('/','\\');` and any other alternative option or not?

```
PatientImage image = patientServiceImage.getImageUrl(imageId, imageuri);
System.out.println("imageuri is" + image);
String strurl=image.getImageurl();

String str =strurl.replace('/','\\');
System.out.println("Image Url Checking"+str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , its working

```
String str =strurl.replace("/","\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

So I tried it using String.replace exactly like you gave here:

```
String str = strurl.replace('/','\\');
```

And that worked fine for me, and tbh it's probably the safest and best way to go in my opinion. Don't fix stuff that ain't broke.